# If $f$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ prove $f(x)\geq f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0) \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Proof by MVT.

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

$f$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}$ then $f'$ is strictly increasing in $\mathbb{R}$

If $x<x_0$

$f$ continuous in $[x,x_0]$ and differentiable in $(x,x_0)$, from the *Mean Value Theorem*

\begin{align*}
  \exists &\xi \in (x,x_0):f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}  \\
 x_0>\xi \Rightarrow   f'(x_0)&>f'(\xi) \\ \Rightarrow  f'(x_0)&>\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \\
  \Rightarrow  f'(x_0)(x-x_0)&<f(x)-f(x_0) \\ \Rightarrow  f(x)&>f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)
\end{align*}
If $x>x_0$

$f$ continuous in  $[x_0,x]$ and differentiable in $(x_0,x)$, from the *Mean Value Theorem*

\begin{align*}
  \exists & \xi \in (x_0,x):f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}  \\
 x_0<\xi \Rightarrow   f'(x_0)&<f'(\xi) \\  \Rightarrow f'(x_0)&<\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \\
  \Rightarrow f'(x_0)(x-x_0)&<f(x)-f(x_0) \\ \Rightarrow  f(x)&>f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)
\end{align*}

Edit:

If $x=x_0$ then $f(x_0)\geq f(x_0) $ which holds as an equality.

In the end $f(x)\geq f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0) \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Isn't it the case that $f$ is convex iff $f′$ is monotonically increasing? I guess it shouldn't be "strictly" from that statement but I've seen it used. I'm using the definition: Let $f$ continuous on $\Delta$ and differentiable inside $\Delta$ then: $f $is convex if $f'$ is strictly increasing in $\Delta$. That's the definition from my school book.

Comment: Oh, I see...I missed the derivative thing. I shall delete my comment...Yes, it is true that the first derivative must be increasing and thus, if the function is differentiable twice its second derivative must be positive.

Comment: Note that in the title you got the inequality wrong!

Comment: Oh no.. not again. I always do that.

Comment: Regardless, would you say this is an acceptable way to go here?

Comment: A clue of easier proof(and perhaps you're aware about it): Think about the TANGENT of the graph $f(x)$.